# how to download file after completing login form in redirected link

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download some `.tgz` files from a website by python code.
when I click the file link, it goes to another page which want's me to fill a form (for login) and after filling the form, it goes back to file link and download starts.
I have tried `python3` and `requests` but I was not successful :

My code:

```
import requests
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

payload={'username':'salvandi69@gmail.com','password':'123asdzxc'}

myurl="https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/dnb_composites/v10//201707/vcmslcfg/SVDNB_npp_20170701-20170731_75N060W_vcmslcfg_v10_c201708061200.tgz"
myurl2="https://eogauth.mines.edu/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&scope=email%20openid&client_id=eogdata_oidc&state=VyIetf3UzkQbxOjX-jJ-ae5lMaM&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Feogdata.mines.edu%2Feog%2Foauth2callback&nonce=DRL2KruY5oxbgo2G6HxNHX-CgiMoxfF6FdGOV-FK65o"

r = requests.post(myurl2, verify=False, data=payload, timeout=6)

print(r.text)
```

`myurl` is file link and `myurl2` is redirected link
the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="login-pf">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Log in to Earth Observation Group Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/auth/resources/afx5f/login/eog/img/favicon.ico" />
            <link href="/auth/resources/afx5f/common/keycloak/node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="/auth/resources/afx5f/common/keycloak/node_modules/patternfly/dist/css/patternfly-additions.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="/auth/resources/afx5f/common/keycloak/lib/zocial/zocial.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="/auth/resources/afx5f/login/eog/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="login-pf-page">
    <div id="kc-header" class="login-pf-page-header">
      <div id="kc-header-wrapper" class=""><div class="kc-logo-text"><span>EOG</span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-pf ">
      <header class="login-pf-header">
            <div id="kc-locale">
                <div id="kc-locale-wrapper" class="">
                    <div class="kc-dropdown" id="kc-locale-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" id="kc-current-locale-link">English</a>
                        <ul>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=de">Deutsch</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=no">Norsk</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=ru">Русский</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=sv">Svenska</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=pt-BR">Português (Brasil)</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=lt">Lietuvių</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=en">English</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=it">Italiano</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=fr">Français</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=zh-CN">中文简体</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=es">Español</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=cs">Čeština</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=ja">日本語</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=sk">Slovenčina</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=pl">Polish</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=ca">Català</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=nl">Nederlands</a></li>
                                <li class="kc-dropdown-item"><a href="/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?kc_locale=tr">tr</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <h1 id="kc-page-title">        We are sorry...
</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="kc-content">
        <div id="kc-content-wrapper">


        <div id="kc-error-message">
            <p class="instruction">Invalid Request</p>
        </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may need `requests.Session()` to keep cookies after login - because download may need this cookies to confirm that you really logged in. Script may also need to behave like real human, first `get()` original page, next `post()` login data, and finally `get()` file - and all with `Session()` to get all cookies. And sometimes servers may check also `headers`. Especially `User-Agent` which should be something like `Mozilla/5.0 ...` but `requests` sends `python/3.8 ...`

Comment: can you explain more? I used s=requests.Session() , s.get , s.post , r=s.get. but was not successful

Comment: you may need also headers - use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome to see what web browser sends to server. But maybe server use JavaScript to controle access and then requests can be useless because it can't run JavaScript. And then you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser.

Comment: I confused ! I'm new on python

Comment: web scraping is not easy job. You have to learn not only Python but also how to use `DevTools`, how to work `HTTP` protocol, how to work `AJAX` in JavaScript. But sometimes portals use tools which can recognize script (bot/spamer/hacker) and block it - even if you use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which use real web browser.

Comment: can you tell me about this website?

Comment: do you mean website from your question? I don't know how it work - I don't know how you normally login to this page, which page you open as first. it may add different values not only in cookies but also in URL. I don't know how it works when you login - I don't have account and login/password. I can only say that you can use `DevTools` to see all requests from browser to server, see if they change values in urls and cookies - and you my try to do the same in code. If server uses new value in URL in every request then you have to find it in HTML (using `lxml`) and add to your url in every req.

Comment: for downloading i use: 'https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/dnb_composites/v10//202004/vcmslcfg/SVDNB_npp_20200401-20200430_75N060W_vcmslcfg_v10_c202006121200.tgz' .As I have understood, it redirects to unique login web page for every request and I got it by **r.url** in my new code. but after posting data, its HTML shows an error: "We are sorry... Invalid Request" I cant understand where is the problem

Comment: it seems you didn't send all needed informations or system is much clever than you think. first: everytime when I click `.tgz` then browser redirect me to url with different values `state` and `nonce`. You send `username` and `password` but browser send elements in POST - there are hidden fields in `form` - and you can see it in `DevTools` when open tab `Network` click link send to server and select `Request` details on right side (silimar to video [Firefox Devtools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvvWQ9qWOmI))

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is: you send `POST` to url with login page but `form` doesn't have to do this. You should check `<form action=...>` to get correct url for `POST`.

I use `BeautifulSoup` to get this information from `HTML`.

I don't have `username` and `password` to test all elements but at least now `POST` gets page with login form and message `Invalid username or password.` instead of page with `Invalid Request`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

s = requests.Session()
#s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

# --- use tgz to get login page -------

url_tgz = "https://eogdata.mines.edu/wwwdata/viirs_products/dnb_composites/v10//201707/vcmslcfg/SVDNB_npp_20170701-20170731_75N060W_vcmslcfg_v10_c201708061200.tgz"

r = s.get(url_tgz)
#print(r.status_code)
#print(r.history)
print('\n--- url page ---\n')
print(r.url)

# --- find url in form ---

soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
item = soup.find('form') 
url = item['action']

print('\n--- url form ---\n')
print(url)

print('\n--- url page == url in form ---\n')
print( r.url == url )

# --- login ---

payload = {
    'username': 'salvandi69@gmail.com',
    'password': '123asdzxc',
    'credentialId': '',
}

r = s.post(url, data=payload)
#print(r.status_code)
#print(r.history)
#print(r.url)
#print(r.text)

# --- result ---

print('\n--- login ---\n')
soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
item = soup.find('span', {'class': 'kc-feedback-text'})
if item:
    print('Message:', item.text)
else:
    print("Can't see error message")

print('\n--- end ---\n')
```

Comment: I don't know why but this code stops after printing : print( r.url == url ) result. I think there is a problem with r = s.post ... my user and pass is: 'vfouladgar@gmail.com' and '123asdzxc'

Comment: it works with false username and password and shows 'Invalid username and password' but with true account stops !

Comment: after login you have to run again `get( file.tgz )` to download it - but I don't know if page doesn't use other method to block scripts - maybe it will need more work.

Comment: I think the problem is in posting login data. Because it stops on `s.post(...)` and doesn't print `print('\n--- login ---\n')`

Comment: it can one of the method to stop scripts/bots/spamers/hackers - it blocks connection so code can't work :) You may have to go back to `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` and see what else browser sends to server - and you have to do the same. Script may have to behave like real human. Or maybe use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of `requets` and it will behave much more like real human

Comment: it seems that the code gives authentication information and opens another action-url and then redirect to third-url. in these steps it gives cookie and location from first and second url !!! I can say any thing more! and I dont know how to encounter !

Comment: I can't help you. Maybe use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)